# d3.event is getting null in typescript implementation

Tags: javascript, d3.js, typescript

this is here the two implementation doing the same thing, here i tried to produce the minimum repo, with two implementation.
This one is without using typed definition of D3

```
    import React from 'react';

export class ChartExample extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let margin = {top: -5, right: -5, bottom: -5, left: -5},
            width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        this.zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
            .scaleExtent([1, 10])
            .on("zoom", this.zoomed.bind(this));

        this.svg = d3.select(React.findDOMNode(this))
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.right + ")")
            .call(this.zoom);

            let rect = this.svg.append("rect")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height)
                .style("fill", "none")
                .style("pointer-events", "all");

            this.container = this.svg.append("g");
            this.container.append("g")
                .attr("class", "x axis")
                .selectAll("line")
                .data(d3.range(0, width, 10))
                .enter().append("line")
                .attr("x1", function(d) { return d; })
                .attr("y1", 0)
                .attr("x2", function(d) { return d; })
                .attr("y2", height);

            this.container.append("g")
                .attr("class", "y axis")
                .selectAll("line")
                .data(d3.range(0, height, 10))
                .enter().append("line")
                .attr("x1", 0)
                .attr("y1", function(d) { return d; })
                .attr("x2", width)
                .attr("y2", function(d) { return d; });
    }
    zoomed() {
        this.container.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
    }

    render() {
        return <svg height={400} width={500}></svg>;
    }
}
```

Here Using the Typed definition of D3,

```
/// <reference path="../../../tsd.d.ts" />
import * as React from "react";
import * as d3 from "d3";

export class ExampleGraph extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
    private i: d3.Primitive;
    private duration: d3.Primitive;
    private svg: d3.Selection<d3.selection.Group>;
    private zoom: d3.behavior.Zoom<d3.selection.Group>;
    private container: d3.Selection<d3.selection.Group>
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    componentDidMount(): void {
        let margin = {top: -5, right: -5, bottom: -5, left: -5},
            width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        this.zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
            .scaleExtent([1, 10])
            .on("zoom", this.zoomed.bind(this));

        this.svg = d3.select(React.findDOMNode(this))
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.right + ")")
            .call(this.zoom);

        let rect = this.svg.append("rect")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .style("fill", "none")
            .style("pointer-events", "all");

        this.container = this.svg.append("g");
        this.container.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .selectAll("line")
            .data(d3.range(0, width, 10))
            .enter().append("line")
            .attr("x1", function(d) { return d; })
            .attr("y1", 0)
            .attr("x2", function(d) { return d; })
            .attr("y2", height);

        this.container.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .selectAll("line")
            .data(d3.range(0, height, 10))
            .enter().append("line")
            .attr("x1", 0)
            .attr("y1", function(d) { return d; })
            .attr("x2", width)
            .attr("y2", function(d) { return d; });
    }
    zoomed(): void {
        this.container.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
    }
    render(): JSX.Element {
        return <svg height={500} width={500}></svg>;
    }
}
```

Both doing the same thing, this is just the minimum implementation of showing Zoming,

But for some reason (in typed implementation , 2nd one) when i tried to zoom (Using wheel), the breakpoint is getting hit to zoomed function but d3.event is getting null, which is perfectly fine on the other implementation (without TypeScript) Can some please help me with this, may be i am registering zoom event in a wrong way, Please suggest, Any suggestion will be really helpful.

In TypeScript implementation the compiler is also giving error saying :

```
Property 'translate' does not exist on type 'Event.
Property 'scale' does not exist on type 'Event'.
```

Comment: May be a related issue. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/bwdNirt2uEU

Comment: more reference: https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/pull/4623

Comment: did you ever fix this

Answer (score 1):

This is how i fixed this:

```
// Here you create your zoom listener...
this.zoomListener = d3.behavior.zoom<d3Common.INode>()
            .scaleExtent(this.props.graphConfig.scaleExtent)
            .on('zoom', () => this.zoomHandler());

// here you get your scale and translate from your above zoom listener listener...
private zoomHandler(value: number): void {
        this.svg.attr('transform', 'translate(${this.zoomListener.translate()})scale(${this.zoomListener.scale()})');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. The issue was `import * as d3 from "d3";`.  In order to get access to `d3.events` you need to `import d3 from 'd3';`.  A similar issue can occur with some features of `moment`.  See http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#import

Comment: In the meantime `d3.event` does not exist anymore. Use `function (this, event)` as your listener and then directly `event.transform` instead of `d3.event.translate` (the `translate` has been changed to `transform`)